# Automatically set an updatedAt time on a record

Tags: ember.js

How can I set the value of an updatedAt field on a record to the current time whenever the values of any properties of that record change?

I see that `DS.Model` has a `didUpdate` event (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#event_didUpdate) - maybe I should add an observer on this (but there are no examples in the docs of listening to events that I can find). Or maybe some sort of computed property on the model would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe didUpdate event like that:

```
// in controller with model, that extends Ember.Model class
this.get('model').on('didUpdate', functuion() {
    // set time value to updatedAt property
});
```

Just don't forget to remove observer when it is no longer necessary.

P.S. I'am pretty sure that this kind of model's properties (createdAt, updatedAt, etc) must have read only status for the client side. In this case, updatedAt property must be set to properly value on the server-side and returned to the client after that (with others properties, like ember expects).

P.P.S. If you need to encapsulate this observer in model's code, you could do it like so:

```
  init: function() {
      this._super.apply(this, arguments);

      this.on('didUpdate', function() {
          // logic
      });
  }
```

Comment: I'm using localstorage so it's right to set on the client side. By the way, what do you mean by "when it's no longer necessary"? When the route changes I should remove it, then add it again if they come back to that route? Also, is there any way to set this directly on the model? I use the same model with 2 different controllers so want to keep it DRY.

Comment: I mean to remove an observer, when client not working with this model. If model's life cycle is same as application's, then you can not worry about it. I'am not sure about setting values inside model itself. It's like database entry that changes itself. I think the best way to implement DRY method here is to group model's management code to the model's controller. Then, you could use this controller in other places. But if there are many models, then it might be the case where placing management code to model is the right decision. You can do it by overriding `init` method in model's class.